# Calculating the number of draws to finish permutations with replacement

Tags: probability, permutations

Trying to solve a permutation with replacement problem and I'm stuck.

An urn has 3 red balls, 3 blue balls, and 3 yellow balls. Each "turn", you draw a ball at random and make note of the color. Then you put the ball back (e.g. with replacement) before drawing the next ball.

Your draw is considered complete once you have drawn 13 balls, but you cannot count towards completion more than 5 from any 1 color. So for example, if on your 13th draw, you have drawn 6 red, 2 blue, and 5 yellow, you would need to keep drawing until you have a third blue. In theory the number of draws could be infinite. So the only possible "finishes" are:

5 or more red, 5 or more blue, 3 yellow

5 or more red, 3 blue, 5 or more yellow

3 red, 5 or more blue, 5 or more yellow

5 or more red, 4 blue, 4 yellow

4 red, 5 or more blue, 4 yellow

4 red, 4 blue, 5 or more yellow

Question 1: How many draws will it take on average to "finish"?

Question 2: What is the probability that it takes exactly 13 draws, 14 draws, 15 draws, etc to "finish"?

Question 3: How to solve both 1 and 2 if not starting from scratch? For example, say you have already drawn 4 red, 3 blue, and 1 yellow. How many new draws to "finish", and the probability for each possible number of draws.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself? Perhaps you could edit these into the question

Comment: I can tell you what I've tried. First I set it up in Excel and ran 1 million simulations to get an approximate answer. This gave me a target that would help me know if I got the right answer.

Comment: First I set it up in Excel and ran 1 million simulations to get an approximate answer. Second, I thought it would be easier to start with the second question and the simplest scenario: I have 2/5/5 and need to draw a third red. Then did 1/5/5 and need to draw 2 more red, then 0/5/5 and need to draw 3 more red. This was easy to figure out by listing out all the permutations, but I couldn't figure out a generalized formula that worked. And when I made the leap to needing 2 colors, 3/3/5 for example, the permutations got harder and I hit a wall.